# xpath: find element by text between tags

Tags: selenium, xpath

We can find element by inner text, for example:

```
<span>
    <div>
        Example Text
    </div>
    <div>
        Other Text
    </div>        
</span>
```

In this case we can use follow xpath: `//span/div[contains(text(), 'Example')]`

**But how can I found element when the text exist out of the tag?** 
For example:

```
<span>
    <div id="1">
        ...........
    </div>
    Example Text
    <div id="2">
        ......    
    </div>        
    Other Text
</span>
```

And shat if, I haven't `id` on the div tags, and I can't use order?

```
<span>
    ...........
    <div>
        ...........
    </div>
    Example Text
    <div>
        ......    
    </div>        
    Other Text
</span>
```

Comment: tag your binding language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use xpath axes to select siblings.

`//text()[contains(.,"Example")]//preceding-sibling::div[1]`

Comment: What if, I haven't `id` on the div tags, and I can't use order?

Comment: This xpath should be order-independent, as long as your desired `div` is always the first sibling before the text. If not, I'll need a different example of what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this XPath

```
//span[contains(text(),'Example Text')]//div[@id='1']
```

For the first `div`.
The same for the second `div`

```
//span[contains(text(),'Example Text')]//div[@id='2']
```

Generally, in this case the "Example Text" text is contained by the parent `span` element.
So you can locate the parent `span` according to this text and then drill down to the child `div`.

Comment: What if, I haven't `id` on the div tags, and I can't use order?

Comment: You asking about situation when there is no any kind of unique identification and not order for the elements you wish to get their texts? And you still wish to get texts of each such element? Right?